# Problem with login button value

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I've just started couple of days ago with codeigniter, I have a following problem. When I set value of login button to "" (no value) in order to style it with css properly the login form won't work, the value needs to be login, is there a way arround it I'm sure there is got to be the way.. Here is some code ..

Controller :

```
<?php

class Login extends Controller {
//  var $success = '';


    function Login()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $success_tmp   = '0';
        $this->load->model('Member');

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library(array('encrypt', 'form_validation', 'session'));



        $this->form_validation->set_rules('member_username', 'User', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('member_pass', 'Password', 'required');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<em>','</em>');



        if($this->input->post('login'))
        {
            if($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                if ($this->Member->check_login() == 1 ) 
                {
            //  $this->session->set_userdata('');
                redirect('index_main');

                $success_tmp = 1;
                }
            }
        } 
        if ($success_tmp != 1) 
        {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('login_form');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login/index/');
    }





}
```

Here is my view file :

```
<div id="page-top"><h1>Existing users</h1></div>

<div class="login_center">
<div class="login_logo"></div>

<?$attributes = array('class' => 'login_form', 'id' => 'login_form');?>
<?$login_dugme = array('class' => 'login_button', 'name' => 'login', 'value' => 'login');?>
<?=form_open('login/index/', $attributes);?>





        <ul class="login_form">
                 <li>
            <?=form_label('Username', 'member_username')?>
            <?=form_input('member_username', set_value('member_username'))?>
            <?=form_error('member_username')?>
        </li>

        <li>
            <?=form_label('Password', 'member_pass')?>
            <?=form_password('member_pass')?>
            <?=form_error('member_pass')?>
        </li>
               </ul>









</div>
<div class="login_bottom"><?=form_submit($login_button);?></div>
<?=form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use a space instead of "" for the button...  It may work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($this->input->post('login')))
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: I get error when I use that Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in

Comment: Where did you put it? You should replace if($this->input->post('login')) by if(isset($this->input->post('login'))) that it also works if the post value of the login button is transmitted, but empty.